# PyQt 4.7 - ImportError after installing on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, importerror

I've been trying to install **PyQt 4.7** on Vista, but I am getting an ImportError when I try to do: `from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui`.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I've checked my System Path, and **C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin** is on there.

I can't run any of the examples, but the Designer, Assistant and Linguist run fine.

*I am using ActivePython 3.1, if that makes any difference. And I haven't had any previous version of PyQt installed.*

---

**Edit:**

I've copied the QtCore4 and GtGui4 dlls to **C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4**. That fixes some of the examples, but I still can't use the example browser.

Comment: I don't think PyQt4 was installed properly... try reinstalling (see my updated answer below)

Comment: Downvoters: Please give me a reason, so I can learn from that.

Comment: For DLL errors like this, you can use Microsoft's Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see exactly which DLLs are being searched for, where they were searched for, and whether each search failed/succeeded.

Comment: Check the path, your path for Qt/bin should be ahead of the path of Python and Python/Scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure there is a `\bin` directory for your version of PyQt?
I am running PyQt 4.4, and all my binaries are right in:

**C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4**

Which is what I have my path pointing too.
It sounds like PyQt4 was installed improperly... did you run this?

```
python setup.py install
```

There **shouldn't** be a bin there...

Comment: The designer and all dlls are in the bin directory.

Comment: No, I ran the binary installer.

Comment: It works now, after I copied all the files of the bin directory and changed my path.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to chime in that I had the same problem on a WinXP install of:

- python 2.7
- Qt 4.7.1 (10.05)
- PyQt 4.8.1

I used the windows installer version of all 3 of those items.

Copying the contents of the **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin** folder up to the main PyQt folder (**C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4**) stopped the 'dll not found' errors that python was throwing.

Answer (score 1):

Also chiming in. I installed both python 2.6 and PyQt 4.8.3 on a Windows 7 machine using the windows installers (I did NOT run 'python setup.py install').

I tried to run spyder (which requires PyQt 4.4 or greater) and failed because it couldn't find the PyQt .dlls. I copied all the .dlls from the \Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin folder to the \Lib\site-packages\PyQt4 folder, and spyder launches just fine.

Answer (score 1):

PyQt installation also depends on the version of python installed on your platform.Python3.+ is incompatible with Python version < 3.x.

I was facing the same problem as I have Python 2.7 installed on my machine but I downloaded the latest binary which was PyQt-Py3.2-x86-gpl-4.9.exe. If you see here the binary has python version also mentioned in name after PyQt which is Py3.2. I uninstalled PyQt and installed PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.9.exe which points to Python 2.7 and it fixed the problem.

Probably they could have mentioned the naming convention online or in some documentation to be more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I got my program running from within Eclipse but when I tried running it directly from the command line I still got the same error.

I solved it by renaming the **C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\PyQt4** directory. (I'm guessing leftovers from a previous PyQt install)

I am using ActivePython.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two possible error conditions

**1. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

then you have to check your PyQT version is comptible with your python. In other words, if you use python 3.3, then you can only use PyQT for python3.3 and python 3.3 will not work with PyQT for python3.4

This was the problem I met. I solved it with re-install it

**2. Import Error: DLL load failed: %1 then something strange on a different encoding Win32.**

then it would be a OS problem. If you use 32bit Python then you have to use 32bit PyQt, so do 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I could fix those errors on Windows 7:

1. Get the PyQt4 wheel from
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4.
   Make sure that the version is exactly the same as your Python version (i.e. Python 3.3 doesn't work with PyQT for Python 3.4). Also make sure to download the 64bit version if you are on a 64bit machine and vice versa.
2. Extract the wheel with 7zip
3. Rename the PyQt4-4.11.4.data (or similar) directory to PyQt4
4. Go to PyQt4\purelib\PyQt4\ and move everything to the root PyQt4 folder. You can delete the purelib folder now
5. Copy the whole PyQt4 folder to your Python interpreters 'site-packages' folder (e.g. C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages)
6. Go to PyQt4\data\Lib\site-packages and move all the files to C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed MSVCP140.dll. I have solved this problem by dowloading Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Got this solution from [MSVCP140.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998902/msvcp140-dll-missing)

I am using Pyqt4 and Python 3.6 in Windows7.