# Python3.5 on Win7x64 can not load from Qt5 module QtWidgets

Tags: windows, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I've installed python 3.5.0

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Then installed Qt5 : pip install python-qt5.

Here code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello")
button.setFixedSize(400, 400)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

It return error:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/py_test/test_qt5/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/py_test/test_qt5/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is my PATH:

C:\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Python35\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\;

Please adwise.
Thanks

UPDATE:
I have Qt5Widgets.dll and QtWidgets.pyd in C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, PyQt5 will not work with python3.5

downgrading to python 3.4 solved problem

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the binaries in `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\` or are them in `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\bin`?

Check if `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\bin` exists and add the path to your environment `PATH` variable.

Comment: i have binaries/dlls in C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\ , and there is no bin\ directory

C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\ exist in PATH variable

Comment: @Vlad Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140836/pyqt-4-7-importerror-after-installing-on-windows?

Comment: i've reinstalled to x86 python35, and getting 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.' now

Comment: hey i am using python 3.6 i found the bin folder in C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin   . So try adding that to environment variable path in windows 7