# Can't get ipython notebook to work

Tags: python, ipython

I'm fairly new to programming. I am a student of Mathematics and one of my modules has python programming as part of it. I was told to download python 3.5 and, using cmd and pip, to download the following packages which I did:
matplotlib,
ipython,
notebook,
numpy,
scipy,

After downloading them I entered, in cmd, ipython notebook but an error message saying "The program can;t start because MSVCP140.dll is missing from your compute. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I have tried to reinstall python and the aforementioned packages but the same message keeps popping up. What can I do to fix this?

Sorry if my post is in the wrong section of the forum, this is my first time on Stackexchange.

Comment: I believe it's a  C++ runtime library. Which you can download simply from Microsoft.

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32998963/478656 - you need the Visual C++ runtimes.

Comment: Would I need the x64 version or the x86 version? My OS is x64 but I downloaded the 32 bit version of Python

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks for the help! :)