# WAMP shows missing MSVCP140.dll when installing

Tags: windows, dll, wamp

An alert message saying missing MSVCP140.dll files when I tried installing Wamp Server 2.5 on my Windows 7 machine.

I found out that MSVCP140.dll is a runtime support DLLs -> "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" file.

However this alert still shows up even after I downloaded from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and installing it.

I also looked into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998902/msvcp140-dll-missing) but no luck as well :(

Comment: Check for 64 bit vs 32 bit mismatch. Also, try asking on serverfault and superuser forums since this is not really a programming question.

Comment: If you run Windows 64bit and WAMPServer 64bit You need to install BOTH the 32bit and 64bit msvcp140 runtime. Also make sure you have these installed before running the wampserver install. If not uninstall and reinstall wampserver.

Answer (score 7):

I am currently running Windows 64bit and WAMPServer 64bit. I installed BOTH the 32bit and 64bit msvcp140 runtime via this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) before running the wampserver installation. And it worked!

Thanks RiggsFolly!:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing wamp on windows 10.This worked for me.

Download VCRUNTIME140.DLL
Copy the dll file to C:\Windows\System32 using administrative privileges.
Try reinstalling apache.