# MSVCP140.dll missing in VS2013 + Win7

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.2.0 and run `CannyStill.cpp` according to the following instructions.

- [Installation Cheat Sheet 1 - OpenCV 3 and C++.pdf](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_Windows_10_Installation_Tutorial)

I am using VS2013 plus Win7.

[image]

- I have [set the Runtime Library to `/MTd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32999084/159072).

[image]

- I have installed [VC++ 2015 Redistributables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998963/159072).

[image]

but the problem is not going away.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your OpenCV was compiled with another Visual Studio compiler (2015). With the redistributables you will get the release version of the dll, but not the debug one. The error is complaining about

> MSVCP140**D**.dll

which is for debuging.

**Possible solutions**

1. You can recompile OpenCV (why is not compiled with the same visual studio in the first place?) with VS2013 and use that one.
2. Install VS2015 and use that one.
3. Compile it and run it in release mode.

Choose whichever suits you :)