# opencv_world300d.dll is missing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am using VS2013 plus Win7.

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0.0 and run `CannyStill.cpp` according to the following instructions.

- [Installation Cheat Sheet 1 - OpenCV 3 and C++.pdf](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_Windows_10_Installation_Tutorial)

Since my [previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51019658/159072) didn't work out well, I am now trying with OpenCV 3.0.0.

But there is a new problem.

[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Here are my configurations:

1. 

[image]

2. 

[image]

3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just copy that dll where your sources are (Project folder), and that will fix it.

Visual studio tries to execute the compiled exe in the location of the sources, so it needs the .dll there.

Answer (score 0):

a good option is copy opencv_world300d.dll (debug mode) or opencv_world300.dll(release mode) but it's too boring...
I recommend you finding the directory which containt opencv_world300d.dll or opencv_world300.dll and edit your environment variable :
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UPsl.png)

:D