# How do I run a windows 10 debug build on a windows 7 test machine

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-debugging, vcredist

I am trying to run a debug build of my software, built in Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 7 test machine.

In microsoft documentation for
[Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable?view=vs-2015)
It tells me to get the .DLL files from

```
Program Files (x86) directory in \Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\
```

*however* the msvcp140d.dll (and associated files) located there are Windows 10 dlls, and internally link to the Windows 10 UCRT libraries that are not present or compatible with Windows 7.

I assume what I need is the location (either on my system already or downloadable from microsoft sources) of the correct DLLs to drop onto the test machine.

Can anyone help me find the correct DLLs?

Comment: Compile with static linking?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998902/msvcp140-dll-missing

Comment: At the moment, that's not an option, in part because I'd need to change my buildsystem to build Qt5 with static linkage.
I'm also concerned statically linking to the libraries would lock the application completely into Windows 10 because of the default UCRT linkage.

Comment: Also I'm not missing msvcp140.dll, I'm missing msvcp140d.dll