# ImportError: DLL load failed:'PyQt4'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have installed PyQt with the installer (4.11.4 so that should be good. Im on windows 10 running Python 3.5.

Python install path:

```
C:\Python34
```

PyQt install path:

```
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

**Update:** I reinstalled and renamed the folder. Now i get this message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Cannot find the module
```

I have these folders added to my path:

```
C:\Python
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

Comment: If you're running Python 3.5, why is it installed in `C:\Python34`?

Comment: Thats the old folder i had from previous installations. Think this matters?

Comment: Potentially. Python might be searching in the 3.5 folder so it can't find your library. Have you checked your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to see if it's searching in that folder?

Comment: Changed it just to be sure, see my update.

Comment: Did you mean `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`? You said that you installed it in `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`.

Comment: I have reinstalled both to prevent any problems. It is installed in     `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4` now.

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140836/pyqt-4-7-importerror-after-installing-on-windows)? It seems to be similar to your new issue.

Comment: I have, similar indeed but no solution for me there.